# How to merge 2 apps on Itunes App store and make one App?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've been struggling with an issue that, i got an apple account on which i got several apps, now the thing is, i got one app live on app store, around year back and my team deleted that app from sale on app store but that app is in my account yet, now after an year i tried to live that app again, now apple is not allowing me to publish the app because of "App name already exists", i released the app with different name but now the problem is my client needs that app live on store with same name which was deleted! now please guide me is there any way to live that app with old name or merge these two apps with previous name, because it is kind of very critical situation for me to handle.

There is an option for Transfer app on itunesconnect, what does it mean and how can i use this functionality properly?

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that there is no way to do this through the interface provided by iTunes Connect.

We have in the past however sent an support request to the team that deals with iTunes Connect and they have sorted out duplicates and messed up bundle id's in the past.

When yo go to 'Contact Us' there is the option to ask a question, I would Suggest you pick 'Removing my App from the App Store'.

But explain your problem, and it is likely they will be able to help.